# how to allow to show html in my div | Angular 7

Tags: angular, text-editor

I have text-editor form `"ngx-editor": "^4.1.0"`.In result of typing I have for example this.

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="background-color: transparent;">awd d awd awd</span></div><div style="text-align: center;"><span style="background-color: transparent;"><br></span></div><div style="text-align: left;"><span style="background-color: transparent;">ewfewfsefsefe</span></div>
```

but when I want to display the result of editor I use elementary `{{mytext}}`
But I have my saved html which was generate by text editor such text
http://prntscr.com/p337qz

[innerHTML] show me only text without html element.

How I can show it with all html styles and element?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/security

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

After that set your html

```
<div [innerHtml]="myText | safeHtml"></div>
```

Please examine [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqclee)